# Compass - Unable to connect to any MongoDB Atlas database using compass or otherwise

Tags: mongodb, timeout, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

I have been trying to connect to Atlas using the university.mongodb.com connection string:

`mongodb+srv://m001-student:m001-mongodb-basics@cluster0-jxeqq.mongodb.net/test`

But the compass GUI gives the following error:

`queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster-0-jxeqq.mongodb.net`

I created my own cluster and tried again. But unfortunately, the same error showed up. I tried to write a JavaSript code as (the angular placeholders had the actual values in them):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.amffz.gcp.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("collection-1");
  client.close();
});
```

...which gave me this error:

```
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.amffz.gcp.mongodb.net
  at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:202:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'cluster0.amffz.gcp.mongodb.net'
}
```

In Atlas, I enabled the Network Access in the Security option to :
`0.0.0.0/0`

I disabled my firewall just to be sure that the connection is not being blocked:

`sudo ufw disable`

But nothing seems to work.

Any help?

[Edit]

System Config: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Your system appears to have broken DNS resolution. You can try the non-SRV URI that is also available in atlas.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your response. I tried with the non-SRV URI format. It gives me this error -> MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. I have already added my IP address in the Whitelist IP in Atlas along with 0.0.0.0/0. Why is this happening?

Comment: Well, I figured it out. As you said, I have issues with my machine. I deployed the app on Google Cloud and it's working. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the machine which I was using had some problem with the connectivity.

I figured out the way to solve this. I uninstalled MongoDB. It seemed like it had some configuration issues.
I removed mongodb and mongoose npm packages as well.
Re-installed everything. And viola, it got connected!